# Show ModalPopupExtender1 from code behind after saving data using asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

Issue is resolved now...

I have a simple web form where i need to save the email address and give user success or failure message accordingly in the Modal window and i want to do the validation and process from code behind and then show the Modal window.

Right now when i click on the subscribe button it quickly shows the modal window without executing the codebehind / server side code. Please find sample code below

```
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlMSG" CancelControlID="btnSubscribe"
     TargetControlID="HiddenField1">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Continue to Browse

```
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubscriptionText" CssClass="lblfooterSubscribe" 
                    runat="server" Text="Enter your email to subscribe to our Newsletter" 
                    meta:resourcekey="lblSubscriptionTextResource1"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubscribeEmail" runat="server" CssClass="txtSubEmail" 
                    meta:resourcekey="txtSubscribeEmailResource1"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" runat="server" Text="Subscribe" 
                    CssClass="SubEmailBtn" ValidationGroup="SubEmail" 
                    onclick="btnSubscribe_Click" meta:resourcekey="btnSubscribeResource1" />

        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

```
protected void btnSubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Regex reg = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*");
    string email = txtSubscribeEmail.Text;
    email = Helper.SafeSqlLiteral(email, 2);
    string strSql = "INSERT INTO Subscribe (email, subscribeDate,Language)";
    strSql += "VALUES ('" + email + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "','" + Session["lang"].ToString() + "')";
    int result = 0;
    result = DataProvider.intConnect_Select(strSql);
    lblSubEmailMSG.Visible = true;
    btnSubscribe.Enabled = false;
    //Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

I tried to remove the TargetControlID="btnSubscribe" property from the modalPopupExtender but it generates error saying TargetControlID cant be null or empty even removing the TargetControlID  generates error.

If i use hidden field as TargetControl id then it executes the codebehin but it does the full post back and doesn't show the modalwindow

Please suggest how can i hand this functionality..

What did i do? I resolved the issue by specifying TargeControl as Hidden Field and i was also using response.redirect which by mistake i had left uncommented. It works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ISSUE RESOLVED**

What did i do? I resolved the issue by specifying TargeControl as Hidden Field and i was also using response.redirect which by mistake i had left uncommented. It works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Glad you got your problem solved. Please note

1. That seems to be a lot of work for just showing a modal message. You might want to try & take a look at [JQModal] it is fairly easy for your requirement[1](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)
2. Your current code is exposed to SQL Injection attack. Please use parametrized queries where possible to be safe [Parametrized queries](http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx)